# `Haskell` extension for `VSCode` not working on `Linux`

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell, ghcup, haskell-language-server

I installed `ghcup` and:

- Stack 2.9.1
- HLS 1.8.0
- cabal 3.6.2
- GHC 9.2.5

All of them are the recommended versions(I verified it using `ghcup tui`). Then I installed the `Haskell` extension in `VSCode`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get syntax highlighting (from the `Haskell Syntax Highlighting` extension, which seems to be automatically installed alongside the `Haskell` extension) but there is no Intellisense, no code completion, no error detection and no interactive mode (`-->>>` evaluation). I experimented with different folders and haskell files. The filetype is correct, because every time I open a `.hs` file, the Haskell extension checks for updates. I even installed `Codium`, because I suspected a fault in `VSCode`, but it was the same there as well.

The `hsl` language server doesn't seem to be working in Neovim, either. I uninstalled `ghcup` (`ghcup nuke`) and reinstalled again. The result is exactly the same. I prepended the `PATH` and chose vanilla and non-vanilla Stack integration in either installations.

Am I doing something wrong?

OS: `Linux Mint on Ubuntu 20.04.1`, kernel `5.15.0-56`.

Comment: I also tried `GHC 9.0.2` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Reverting to previous versions of the `Haskell` extension didn't work either. At this point, I think it's the Haskell Language Server, which is causing the problem.

Comment: I just installed HSL version 1.7.0.0 and it didn't fix my problem. Now, however, when I try to go back to version 1.8.0.0, even though `ghcup tui` says it's installed, when I set it, I get a prompt "This Version of HLS you are trying to set is not installed. Would you like to install it first? [Y/N]:" If I pick "Yes", the prompt repeats itself endlessly. If I pick "No", I get an error message: "Version 1.8.0.0 is not installed". `ghcup tui` says both 1.7.0.0 and 1.8.0.0 are available and indeed I have kept both of them. In reality, neither seems available.

Comment: Me too and I abandoned. Each time I solved an issue there was a new one. It's a pity because this extension is really cool.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I just solved it yesteday. I will post a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After around 10 tries, I managed to fix the problem. It turned out I had three problems:

- I had only 12 GB free on my Linux partition, but it seems more are needed. I realised it, when it turned out some `haskell-language-server` files were missing. I enlarged my Linux partition (something I should have done months ago). The new installation installed all files
- The Haskell Language Server HLS was not added to the PATH. I solved it by putting this snippet in `~/.ghcup/config.yaml`:

```yaml
  "haskell.serverEnvironment": {
    "PATH": "${HOME}/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"
  }
```

- The server was now discovered by the `Haskell` VS Code extension but crashed 5 times and gave up on trying. Restarting it manually didn't help. I opened the logs: `View`->`Output`->`Haskell` and saw the error:

```
haskell-language-server-wrapper: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by haskell-language-server-wrapper)
```

It turns out, my Linux Mint distribution uses `GLIBC_2.31`, not `2.32`. This is a very important library, which most applications on the system use. If you are a newbie, it is strongly advised that you DO NOT update it manually.

- Instead, what I did, was install a version of the `HLS`, which used `GLIBC_2.31`. This problem occured in September and was "fixed" but apparently not very well. There are two options:

  - download the `HLS deb10` version manually (didn't work for me):

  ```
  ghcup install hls -u https://downloads.haskell.org/~hls/haskell-language-server-1.8.0.0/h
  ```

  - download using `ghcup tui` HLS version `1.7.0.0` (or whatever newest, which uses your `glibc` version) and a GHC, which supports that particular version of the HLS (in my case `9.0.2`).
- I think it's a good idea to preemptively reinstall the extension, in case it used the PATH to configure the `HLS`, so that its settings are restored to default. It takes up to 20 seconds to initialize the server, so be patient. You can see what's happening in the `Output` window and verify there are no more errors.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This has solved some issues for me, but there's a remaining one: *The Haskell server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes and won't be restarted*. No way to restart it.

Comment: This sounds exactly like my third error. Did you install `Haskell Language Server 1.7.0.0` and `GHC 9.0.2`? More importantly, did you set them (installation doesn't set them automatically)? Could you please open the `Output` tab of the terminal and select the `Haskell` view to see what is the reason the server fails.

Comment: By default, `ghcup` uses versions `HLS 1.8.0.0` and `GHC 9.2.5`, not `1.7.0.0` and `9.0.2`, so you have to install them and set them as default using `ghcup tui`. Please `run ldd --version` in the terminal, so we can be sure what `GLIBC` version you have.

Comment: It works!! I had to add the path to `gcc`. The error was `ghc cannot find gcc`. Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh, yes. During installation it asks you to verify you have a bunch of packages. I am glad everything has worked out for you! Please upvote the question, if you find it useful. I often get a lot of hate on SO and my reputation is very low, so I need every single point I can get :-D.

Comment: I already upvoted!

Comment: I just fixed the bindists for HLS, this should be fixed: https://github.com/haskell/ghcup-metadata/commit/1ba37946e15fdcf7d09de01382e44e1849c87bb2